# Can't check permissions on Directory

Tags: c#, directory, asp.net-3.5, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I have some code and I want to be able to catch System.UnauthorizedAccessException and any other exceptions but it doesn not seem to be working as expected.

The code is:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> GetFilesToShred(string xmlDirectory)
    {
        try
        {
            return Directory.GetFiles(xmlDirectory, "*.xml");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Could not retrieve list of files to shred: " + ex.Message, ex);

            return null;
        }

    }
```

When I give this code a xml directory to which the user does not have access the catch statement gets scipped and the exception gets thrown further up the stack.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

UPDATE: As requested please find below full stack trace:

```
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
 at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize)
 at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks)
at XmlShredder.ShredderGateway.ShredAndWrite(String XmlDirectory, IEnumerable`1 XmlInputFiles, String outputDirectory, Boolean isDebug) in c:\Dev\XmlShredder\XmlShredder\ShredderGateway.cs:line 102
```

Hope this will be more help to answer.

Comment: This sounds rather improbable. Maybe you get yet another exception inside the catch?

Comment: Please provide the full exception stack trace.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I have included stack trace on the update.

Comment: @PMF No other exception inside catch. All it does is it gets the list of files as an IEnumerable<string> but it doesn't realise there is no read/write access to that code.

Comment: As you can see at the bottom of the stack trace, the exception is thrown from a completely different function, so of course this `try` does not catch it.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I understand that. The issue is, the above method gets called before the above function is called. If I could get the check to work in the above method then the last function shown in the trace will not be executed as the program would exit.

Comment: You should not check permissions before doing your actual work. There is the potential that permissions could change between the time you checked them and the time you try to do the actual work. You should simply handle the exception thrown when opening the file in `ShredAndWrite`.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Thanks for all the advice. I will do as you say. I am still not sure why this method would not catch it. Maybe it is because the example path has partial permissions which allows the method to get a list of files but does not allow for using a StreamReader to read data from those files.

Comment: The exception isn't thrown in the function `GetFilesToShred()` that you posted but instead in `ShredAndWrite()`. Being able to list the directory contents does not mean you can modifiy/delete the containing files. Check the exception handling in `ShredAndWrite()`.

Comment: @PMF Thanks. I made the mistake of only checking directory permissions. It was the file permissions that were the problem. :)